# Problems with writing bat files

Tags: batch-file

I've trouble writing in the correct code for bat files that helps me compile java files.

1. Compile java files
2. Move the class file to a folder under the same directory called Classes

My current code goes something like this, `javac -d classes -cp classes -sourcepath resource/*.java`

Unfortunately this is not working properly. Errors saying

> unable to find symbol

comes out.

This is probably because when A.java creates an object Circle, it returns an error because the Circle java file is not compiled and the class file is not created yet. May I know how can I get about this error.

Sorry for the unclear explaination as I'm still trying to remember the proper terms

Comment: Where is your Code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will extract all java files in the folder that you run the file in, and moves the class files to the folder named 'classes' in the same directory.

```
@echo off
javac *.java
move *.class classes
exit
```

Hope this helps!